# CSS - Problem of blured div inside a blured div

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is that I cannot use a blurred element inside another blurred element. I have a blurred header `backdrop-filter: blur(3px);` that has a div with a more blurry background `backdrop-filter: blur(50px);`, but its now work. Both are blurred by 3px.
I need to save the structure and apply the effect, please tell me how this can be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/q1aymg02/42/

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
 body {
    background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/space-game-background-with-landscape-planet_107791-1700.jpg);
   }

.header {
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.header ul a li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background: #ffffffb5;
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
}
</style>

<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <a href=""><li>Dont Blured</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>By 50px</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Only 3px</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This problem is looking similar, check it out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802257/css-div-inside-div-blur

Comment: @Firanek It doesn't seem similar :c There's no blurry div inside blurry div, i have another problem..

Comment: This question has a recent answer using pseudo elements which may help [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997948/backdrop-filter-not-working-for-nested-elements-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backdrop-filter property in CSS is used to apply filter effects, and this behavior is inherited by all of its children. You might be interested in this approach.

```css
 body {
    background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/space-game-background-with-landscape-planet_107791-1700.jpg);
   }

.header {
  
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.header ul a li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background: #ffffffb5;
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
}

.header ul a li::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
}

.header ul a li.blured::before {
  content: "Dont Blured";
}

.header ul a li.by--50px::before {
  content: "By 50px";
}

.header ul a li.only--3px::before {
  content: "Only 3px";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <a href=""><li class="blured">Dont Blured</li></a>
    <a href=""><li class="by--50px">By 50px</li></a>
    <a href=""><li class="only--3px">Only 3px</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the result you are looking for, but use can use this approach to blur the li elements

```
.header ul a li {
  filter: blur(1px);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background: #ffffffb5;
}
```

It will blur everything, including the text.